# Receive CSV format in Strongloop

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to receive some data in csv format, what I read is that StrongLoop only works with json data. So can I receive csv and transform to json to process the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a StrongLoop specific question. It is a general Node.js and data question. As such, I will answer in a generic fashion, but it is applicable to StrongLoop.

You will need to use a library to convert the delimited file into a JavaScript object. There are many packages on npm for reading/parsing/transforming/etc. CSV files: [search npm](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=csv).

The package that I have used extensively is [David's CSV parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/csv).

These libraries will allow you to parse and transform CSV into JavaScript objects (JSON).

Beware, however, that most CSV that I have dealt with does not conform to well formatted CSV. They don't properly escape quotes, quote strings with delimiters, etc.